# print names subdirectories with specific suffix

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, subdirectory

I want to print the names of the files within all subdirectories (I have this already), however *depending* on the subdirectory I  want to add a specific suffix after the name.

For the subdir *gas_station* I want to add the suffix **50**, and for the subdir *golf_course* I want the suffix **51**.

This is what I have, but it doesn't quite work:

```
#!/bin/bash

#lists the subdirectories, these are 'gas_station' and 'golf_course'
for i in $(ls -d */); do 

    if ${i%%/} = 'gas_station'

        then

            find /home/apples/dataset/small_train_B/g/${i%%/}/* -type f -printf "g/"${i%%/}"/""%f 50\n" 
        else

            find /home/apples/dataset/small_train_B/g/${i%%/}/* -type f -printf "g/"${i%%/}"/""%f 51\n" 

    fi

done
```

It prints out the following:

```
...
g/gas_station/00000997.jpg 51
g/gas_station/00000998.jpg 51
g/golf_course/00000017.jpg 51
...
```

However, I require this:

```
...
g/gas_station/00000997.jpg 50
g/gas_station/00000998.jpg 50
g/golf_course/00000017.jpg 51
...
```

Comment: if the number of special cases is low (1 in your case), woudn't it be much simpler to just run 2 different finds (one generating 50 suffix and one a suffix of 51)?

Comment: your result clearly indicates the comparison fails. What is the value of ${%%/} at that time?

Comment: The problem is that you aren't using the `test` command (aka `[`) to test the equality. But this is a needlessly byzantine method.

Comment: @rpy thank for your suggestion! However it seems that solution has been given :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason this won't work?

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in gas_station/*; do
    printf "%s 50\n" "$f"
done
for f in golf_course/*; do
    printf "%s 51\n" "$f"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, very efficient solution! Is there a reason why this doesn't print the strings on a new newline: `printf "%s 50" "$f\n"`

Comment: You pass text as the first parameter, variables as the following. I'll update the answer. If you're going with this solution you should mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for f in $(ls -d */); do
   d=${f%%/}; 
   if [ ${d} = "gas station" ]; 
   then  n=50;
   else  n=51;
   fi; 

   find ${d} -type f -printf "g/"${d}"/""%f $n\n";
done
```

Comment: Parsing the results of `ls` can lead to problems, and variables should always be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You might avoid fiddling with the parameter modifiers and just compare against the proper string:

```
if [ "$i" = 'gas_station/' ]
```

Comment: A single equal sign is fine for comparison, it's POSIX standard. What's missing from your answer and his code is the `test` command: `if [ ${i%%/} = 'gas_station' ]`.